# Trying to write a parser

Tags: parsing, shunting-yard, lr-grammar

I'm trying to parse a syntax using the Shunting Yard (SY) algorithm. The syntax includes the following commands (they're are many many others though!)

```
a + b // a and b are numbers
setxy c d //c,d can be numbers
setxy c+d b+a //all numbers
```

Essentially, setxy is a function but it doesn't expect any function argument separators. This makes it very difficult (impossible?) to do via SY due to the lack of parens and function argument separators.

Any idea if SY can be used to parse a parentheses-less/function argument separator-less function or should I move on to a different parsing algorithm? If so, which one would you recommend?

Thanks!
djs22

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having defined correct grammar you can make http://www.antlr.org/ generate parser for you. Whether it is appropriate solution depends on your homework "requirements".

At least you can generate it and look inside for some hints.

Comment: Parser generator output is usually not for the faint of heart.

Comment: Its more about debugger output - might provide some hints on the process

Comment: To quote from ANTLR's "about" page: _"ANTLR is widely used because it's easy to understand, powerful, flexible, generates human-readable output, ..."_

Answer (score -2):

I don't fully understand what you are trying to do, but perhaps you could use some regex? what are you trying to do write a simple command line program?

Comment: Answering "parser" with "regex" is a mockery of parsing algorithms.

Comment: This would have made more sense as a comment.

Comment: I provided a small subset of the many commands my program is required to interpret. A command line program wouldn't be appropriate given the rest of the spec (I'm not going into detail because its extraneous/I don't want to cheat on my hw).